# How to check a existence of Selenium WebDriver instance

Tags: ruby, selenium

I want `quit` a `Selenium WebDriver` instance if it exists.

```
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x1c387eba browser=:phantomjs>
irb(main):023:0> d.quit
=> nil
irb(main):024:0> d.quit
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
```

Without checking existence of driver, it causes error like this.
I want to write like `d.quit if d.exists?`, but it seems there is no such method.
http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver

How can I quit a `WebDriver` peacefully?

Comment: You could catch exception.

Comment: Thanks, if there is no method provided, I'll do so.

Answer (score 1):

By following @Yevgeniy's advice, I've written like this.

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Driver
  def exists?
    self.window_handle
    return true
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    return false
  end
end
```